# Display total from form in Div on blur using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Have a simple form that I am using to add inputs together. On blur, I have the inputs adding up and displaying in another input field. What I would like is to display the total in a div or h1 tag instead of another input field and there is no submit button in the form to get it to another presentation layer. Any ideas?

The JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function() {
$("body").on("blur", "#vehiclePrice,#estimatedTaxesAndFees,#downPayment,#manufacturerRebate,#tradeInValue,#amtOwedOnTrade,#extendedWarranty,#gapInsurance,#serviceContract", function () {
updateTotal();
});
 var updateTotal = function () {
var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
var input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val()) || 0;
var input3 = parseInt($('#downPayment').val()) || 0;
var input4 = parseInt($('#manufacturerRebate').val()) || 0;    
var input5 = parseInt($('#tradeInValue').val()) || 0;
var input6 = parseInt($('#amtOwedOnTrade').val()) || 0;    
var input7 = parseInt($('#extendedWarranty').val()) || 0;
var input8 = parseInt($('#gapInsurance').val()) || 0;
var input9 = parseInt($('#serviceContract').val()) || 0;           

        $('#total').val(input1 + input2 + input3 + input4 + input5 + input6 + input7 + input8 + input9 - 28435);
 };
var output_total = $('#total');

});

});
```

The HTML:

```
              <label for="vehiclePrice" class="form-control-label vpl">Vehicle Price</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="vehiclePrice" placeholder="Vehicle Price" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
              <label for="estimatedTaxesAndFees" class="form-control-label etfl">Estimated Taxes and Fees</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="estimatedTaxesAndFees" placeholder="Estimated Taxes and Fees" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />

            <form id="downPaymentForm">
                <label for="downPayment" class="form-control-label dpl">Down Payment</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="downPayment" placeholder="Down Payment" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                <label for="manufacturerRebate" class="form-control-label mrl">Manufacturer Rebate</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="manufacturerRebate" placeholder="Manufacturer Rebate" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                <label for="tradeInValue" class="form-control-label tivl">Trade-In Value</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tradeInValue" placeholder="tradeInValue" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                <label for="amtOwedOnTrade" class="form-control-label aotl">Amt Owed on Trade</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amtOwedOnTrade" placeholder="Amt Owed on Trade" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />

              <form id="protectionForm">
                <label for="extendedWarranty" class="form-control-label ewl">Extended Warranty</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="extendedWarranty" placeholder="Extended Warranty" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />

                <label for="gapInsurance" class="form-control-label gil">Gap Insurance</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="gapInsurance" placeholder="Gap Insurance" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                <label for="serviceContract" class="form-control-label scl">Service Contract</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="serviceContract" placeholder="Service Contract" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
            </form>

              <h2 class="total">$28,435</h2>
              <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="$28,435">
```

[Das Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/W32Hg/2/)

Comment: Fiddle link ist kaput

Comment: My bad. I updated it. Thanks Elendi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `total` class to point your `h2` for the total, set its `text` and format the value as currency.

Code:

```
$('.total').text('$'+sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W32Hg/3/

Comment: You just saved me from asking my next question. Thanks Irvin.

Comment: I posted another question for you if you'll provide an answer I'll give you those points too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315277/format-input-fields-with-commas-and-display-in-div-as-numeric-formatted-values

Answer (score 1):

Just target the `<h2>` tag and use `.text` instead of `.val`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHn6X/

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$( "div" ).text( output_total );
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of an h2 tag, you can do this:

```
$(".total").innerText = "some value";
```